# Show workspace file link on jenkins SCM plugin changes page

Tags: eclipse, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I wanted to display workspace file link on SCM changes page with other changelist related info.

For example:

if workspace has a file `<workspace>/foo.txt` then i wanted to display a link (`http://localhost:8080/job/Test1/ws/foo.txt/*view*/`) on changelist page of SCM so that user can click on link and open that file in browser. in this example Test1 is the project name and ws is workspace directory.

How do i get this project name, workspace directory in my jelly file?

I tried

```
<td> <a href="${BUILD_URL}/${item.path}/*view*/"> view </a> </td>
```

but `BUILD_URL` is always empty.

Regards,
rkg

Comment: Basically i wanted to ask that how can we get environment variables value in jelly files?